# How To Get the Confusion Matrix when Using Tflearn

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I want to get confusion matrix
yet for that I need the set of predicated items and labels.
how can I get this data from tflearn for example for this example (Pannous speech_data) https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_speech_recognition_demo/blob/master/demo.py

thanks!

```
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=10, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True,batch_size=batch_size)
_y=model.predict(X)
predictions.append(_y)
labels.append(trainY)
bp()
confusionMat=tf.confusion_matrix(labels,predictions,num_classes=classes,dtype=tf.int32,name=None,weights=None)
print(np.matrix(confusionMat))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_y=model.predict(X)  # predictions
y = train_Y # i think this is actual labels data

tf.confusion_matrix(
labels,               # put y here
predictions,          #put _y here
num_classes=None,
dtype=tf.int32,
name=None,
weights=None
)
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. simple and makes sense:)  . so actually need to add at each iteration the _y and train_Y to the prediction and labels, and then at the end calclulate the confusion matrix?

Comment: tried it but the labels and predictions should be array of classes. yet with tflearn each item is an array with the probability for that class. how should I use this as labels/ prediciton?

Comment: please try to debug and understand code. your confusion matrix expects two array . one label which you have and other is prediction class. so instead returning probability score try to return prediction class. prediction class is where probability score gets classify.!!